# Разные фильтры для разных товаров (как организовать структуру)

Tags: php, база-данных, yii2, хранение-данных

Уважаемые знатоки,предположим есть N различных категорий товаров и у каждого из них разные характеристики, например у кого то есть длина и ширина, у другого вес, у третьего этажность и т.д. Поделитесь своим мнением и опытом, **как организовать структуру хранения этих фильтров в БД, чтобы с легкостью добавлять и убирать фильтры для нужных категорий и добавлять сами фильтры**.  Фильтровать все товары по цене - это слишком просто. Пишу проект на YII2, и хочется для определенного типа товара выводить свой конкретный фильтр(ы), допустим у книг: длина, ширина, вес, а у техники: мощность, стоимость. Есть определенные идеи, но чувствую, что изобретаю велосипед, а вместо колес - костыли

Comment: Вам надо копать в сторону "Динамические атрибуты EAV", "поиск EAV" (в поисковике мне дал аж ссылку на Yii)

Comment: попробуйте посмотреть [несколько](https://www.google.ru/search?q=yii2+EAV)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Например:

1. Таблица товаров
   products 
   id|title
2. Таблица категорий
   categories
   id|title
3. Таблица связей для товаров и категорий
   link_by_categories
   id|id_cat|id_product
4. Таблица с параметрами
   params
   id|title
5. Таблица связей для товаров и параметров
   link_by_params
   id|id_param|id_product

и так далее, если есть свзяь с вашей таблицей параметров, то просто ищете такую связь по БД